# Mono (Xamarin) Compile Issue : Error building target GetReferenceAssemblyPaths

Tags: c#, windows, mono, xamarin

I am having trouble compiling a C# solution with the Xamarin IDE (mono) in windows (vista). The error I'm getting is:

`: error : Error building target GetReferenceAssemblyPaths: UNC paths should be of the form \\server\share.`

I saw another [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19933266/error-building-c-sharp-solution-using-xbuild-mono) that seems straight forward to fix, but I'm not seeing any problems with double-backslashes in my project file - I searched through the project file and there are no instances of double-backslash.

The only other thing I can think is I do have an output path that used a relative path:

..\..\..\bin\

... but, considering the error is having a problem with the '\\server\share', I don't think that is it.

Comment: Windows or OS X? You should add a tag for that.

Comment: Could be an xbuild bug or an error in your project file, can you please either post your .csproj file here or [file a bug report](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=Tools) against Tools / xbuild.

Comment: I'm not sure what this means, but I think the error is stemming from the Build Engine (Use MSBuild build engine...). If this happens to be checked, it will create this error, even on a newly added blank project in a larger solution.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem but only with 4.0 framework. When I switch my project onto 3.5 or 4.5 version I don't have this problem

After long searching I found some workaround - open "lib\mono\4.0\Microsoft.Common.targets" file and commented out

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(ImplicitlyExpandDesignTimeFacades)' == 'true'">
        <DesignTimeFacadeDirectoryRoots Include="$(TargetFrameworkDirectory)" />
        <DesignTimeFacadeDirectories Include="%(DesignTimeFacadeDirectoryRoots.Identity)\Facades\"
            Condition="Exists('%(DesignTimeFacadeDirectoryRoots.Identity)\Facades\')" />
        <_DesignTimeFacadeAssemblies Include="%(DesignTimeFacadeDirectories.Identity)\*.dll"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

in the `<Target Name="GetReferenceAssemblyPaths"` block. After that my project was built successfully